# Помогите пожалуйста написать простенький javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla

Есть контейнер `newprice` с данными, по нажатию кнопки `plus` сумма становится больше в два раза `(например 33 >> 66 >> 99 и т.д.)`, а по нажатию кнопки уменьшается.

```html
<div class="newprice m_l">
  <?php echo $item->price2; ?>
</div>55555
<input type="button" value="plus" onclick="change();">
<input type="button" value="minus" onclick="change('down');">
```

Comment: 1. Причем тут java, который указан в заголовке? 2. где тут какой-либо контекст joomla, зачем его тэг поставлен? 3. правильна ли логика "33 >> 66 >> 99"? Быть может, "33 >> 66 >> 132"?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function change(_dec) {
document.querySelector(".newprice").innerHTML = 
 _dec? +document.querySelector(".newprice").innerHTML / 2 
                //Если аргумент имеется уменьшаем
 : +document.querySelector(".newprice").innerHTML * 2
                //Если аргумента нет увеличиваем
 
}
```

```html
<div class="newprice m_l">33</div>
<input type="button" value="plus" onclick="change();">
<input type="button" value="minus" onclick="change('down');">
```

PS Java и JavaScript - два разных языка

Answer (score 0):

Если `newprice` изначально содержит минимальную цену, которая одновременно является шагом изменения, то лучше записывать это значение в data-атрибут общего контейнера (хоть через PHP, хоть яваскриптом). Несмотря на большее количество кода, так будет проще - особенно если блоков с ценой несколько на странице.

Пример кода, который это демонстрирует:

```js
  // при готовности DOM уже можем работать с элементами
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // добавляем всем блокам дата-атрибут с мин.ценой
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.price-block .newprice'); 
  for (let price of elems)
    price.parentElement.dataset.minPrice = price.textContent; 

    // вешаем обработчики клика 
  elems = document.querySelectorAll('.price-block input[type="button"]'); 
  for (let btn of elems)
    btn.addEventListener('click', onPriceBtnClick); 
});

  // обработчик клика по кнопкам
function onPriceBtnClick(e) {
  let parent  = this.parentElement,
      priceEl = parent.querySelector('.newprice'),   
      price   = +priceEl.textContent; 
    // увеличиваем/уменьшаем на величину мин.цены; присваиваем бОльшую из новой цены, и минимальной 
  price += (this.value === 'plus' ? 1 : -1) * parent.dataset.minPrice; 
  priceEl.textContent = Math.max(price, parent.dataset.minPrice); 
}
```

```css
.price-block, 
.price-block > input {
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 8px; margin: 4px; 
  font: 16px sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

.newprice { font-size: 2em; }
.price-block > input { min-width: 70px; }

.price-block > input[value="minus"] { background: #ebb; }
.price-block > input[value="plus"]  { background: #add; }
```

```html
<div class="price-block">
  <div class="newprice m_l">33</div>
  <input type="button" value="minus">
  <input type="button" value="plus">
</div>
<div class="price-block">
  <div class="newprice m_l">42</div>
  <input type="button" value="minus">
  <input type="button" value="plus">
</div>
```